# Kernel dies while using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, crash

When trying to modify a Pandas DataFrame, the message appears in Jupyter Notebook that the kernel seems to have died. The dataframe is only 2.6MB large (15 columns, 60,000 rows, multiindex), consisting of float64 and categorical dtypes. This problem occurs when trying to export the dataframe to CSV, but also when performing some other operations. However, until some days ago, this problem did not occur while running this exact notebook.

I have force-reinstalled numpy, and updated all my packages with conda, but to no avail.

Any help or advice on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*but also when performing some other operations*" -> can you give more details? You should provide a reproducible code